# Is this the right method to calculate age from date of birth in Tableau when there are duplicate values?

Tags: sql-server, tableau-api

What I am trying to achieve is to calculate age from date of birth in tableau however, due to duplicate records, a user's age will be multiplied however many times it was duplicated. The data source is an SQL database.

[This is the output when I use a regular DOB calculation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4a2AM.png)

[image]

The year of both users are 1998 but admin's age is 76 years old. This is the calculated field that I used to get that output.

`IF [DOB]>DATEADD('year',-DATEDIFF('year',[DOB],TODAY()),TODAY()) THEN
    DATEDIFF('year',[DOB],TODAY())-1
ELSE
    DATEDIFF('year',[DOB],TODAY())
END`

Due to multiple one to many relationships within the database, the record for admin is duplicated four times

[Example of data for admin user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cliPL.png)

[image]

I've tried using level of detail expression in other charts to remove the duplicate data. For this calculation, I've tried doing the same for this chart however, it did not work

```
{INCLUDE [Username]:COUNT(DATEDIFF('year', [DOB], TODAY()))}
```

Is this the correct method for solving this problem or am I going about this problem entirely wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets try this -

Create a calculated field `CalculatedAge` as `{fixed[Username]: max([your_calculated_age])}` and use this field as user's age. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, this works like it should have but I'm have trouble understanding why FIXED is used instead of include.

Comment: see [here](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/calculations_calculatedfields_lod_overview.html). It says _"INCLUDE level of detail expressions compute values using the specified dimensions in addition to whatever dimensions are in the view."_